# For Loop Not Counting Array Values

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

Super rookie here. Just doing a little learning before my C course this semester. I found a book practice problem asking to categorize temperature values in an array. Here's everything I have:

```
// write program to process collection of daily high temps

#include <stdio.h>
    
int main (void)
{
    int temp[26] = {55, 62, 68, 74, 59, 45, 41, 58, 60, 67, 
                    65, 78, 82, 88, 91, 92, 90, 93, 87, 80, 
                    78, 79, 72, 68, 61, 59};

    int i;
    float sum;
    float avg;
    int r1, r2, r3; // range 1, range 2, range 3

    // Loop to catagorize temperature values
    for(i = 0; i <= 26; i++)
    {
        if (temp[i] <= 60)
        {
            r1++;
        }
        else if ((temp[i] > 60) && (temp[i] <= 84))
        {
            r2++;
        }
        else 
        {
            r3++;
        }   

    }

    printf("\nThe number of cold days are: %d", r1);
    printf("\nThe number of pleasant days are: %d", r2);
    printf("\nThe number of hot days are: %d", r3);

    // Loop to take the average temperature
    for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + temp[i];
        avg = sum / i;
    }

    printf("\nThe average temperature of the set is: %f", avg);

    return 0;
}
```

The average computes correctly, however, the codes is not categorizing the temp values in the array correctly. I just learned arrays yesterday. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: This `(temp[i] > 60) && ` is not needed. Try your code withot and think through the logic. Constructs like this only risk creating inconcistencies when the code is changed later. The same kind of vulerability to inconsistency you were actually trapped by in the shown code, using "26" for the array size, 26 initialisers for the array, wrongly `<=26` for the first loop and more or less correctly `<=25` for the second loop, allowed the mistake in the first loop to sneak in. You could have avoided by using the size of the array automatically, with `sizeof(temp)/sizeof(temp[0])` and `<` not `<=`.

Answer (score 1):

You invoked undefined behavior:

1-  by using uninitialized variables `int r1, r2, r3; float sum; float avg;`, you should initialize them as zeros.

2- by accessing `if (temp[i] <= 60)` in your loop `for(i = 0; i <= 26; i++)`, while size of `temp` is 26 (should only access 0 - 25).

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `sum, avg, r1, r2, r3` as 0. Also the range of your array is 0-25, so `for(i = 0; i <= 26; i++)` should be changed to `for(i = 0; i <= 25; i++)`.

```c
// write program to process collection of daily high temps

#include <stdio.h>
    
int main (void)
{
    int temp[26] = {55, 62, 68, 74, 59, 45, 41, 58, 60, 67, 
                    65, 78, 82, 88, 91, 92, 90, 93, 87, 80, 
                    78, 79, 72, 68, 61, 59};

    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    float avg = 0;
    int r1 = 0, r2 = 0, r3 = 0; // range 1, range 2, range 3

    // Loop to catagorize temperature values
    for(i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        if (temp[i] <= 60)
        {
            r1++;
        }
        else if ((temp[i] > 60) && (temp[i] <= 84))
        {
            r2++;
        }
        else 
        {
            r3++;
        }   
    }

    printf("The number of cold days are: %d\n", r1);
    printf("The number of pleasant days are: %d\n", r2);
    printf("The number of hot days are: %d\n", r3);

    // Loop to take the average temperature
    for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + temp[i];
        avg = sum / i;
    }

    printf("The average temperature of the set is: %f\n", avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For incrementing the value of a variable you need to initialize the value to the variable. In this case, the variables are r1,r2 & r3. The increment operator increases its value by 1. But if the value is not assigned before, the operator cant finds the value which would be increased.
Here r1++ similar to r1=r1+1.
so it should be initialized like

```
r1=0,r2=0,r3=0;

r1++; // which means r1=0+1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing solutions in the other answers, I propose this solution which introduces you to the concept of programming defensively. In this case I focus on defending against inconsistencies in non-trivial code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main (void)
{
    int temp[/* auto */] =  {55, 62, 68, 74, 59, 45, 41, 58, 60, 67, 65, 78, 82,
    /* newline shows 2*13 */ 88, 91, 92, 90, 93, 87, 80, 78, 79, 72, 68, 61, 59 };
    /* in case space allows, this allows humans to grasp the total number and e.g.
       notice when the number of initialisers is incorrect; the compiler does not
       mind of course */

    int i=0; /* this init is paranoid, in case loop setup is unusually without init */
    float sum = 0.0f; /* this init is needed, see other answers */
    float avg = 0.0f; /* this init is needed, see other answers */
    int r1 = 0, r2 = 0, r3 = 0; // range 1, range 2, range 3

    size_t length = sizeof(temp)/sizeof(temp[0]); /* avoid need for magic numbers */

    // Loop to catagorize temperature values
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) /* avoid need for magic numbers */
    {
        if (temp[i] <= 60)
        {
            r1++;
        } else if (temp[i] <= 84) /* avoid copy of first treshold */
        {
            r2++;
        } else 
        {
            r3++;
        }   
    }

    printf("The number of cold days are: %d\n", r1);
    printf("The number of pleasant days are: %d\n", r2);
    printf("The number of hot days are: %d\n", r3);

    // Loop to take the average temperature
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) /* avoid need for magic number */
    {
        sum = sum + temp[i];
        avg = sum / i;
    }

    printf("The average temperature of the set is: %f\n", avg);

    return 0;
}
```

You might notice that avoiding magic numbers (using `<`) and a habit of initialising everything would have prevented both problems discussed and solved in the other answers.

You could also introduce a chance that a human spots a mistake, by outputting a little additional information, assuming of course that it does not conflict with your requirements. In which case the additional output could be created in a way to be removable conveniently for delivery, in a generic way in your team. Without that removal mechanism, this demonstrates "unobtrusive" additional info in output (noticably exaggerated, I admit):

```
printf("The average temperature of the set of %i temperatures "
       "(%i of which have been classified) is: %f\n", length, r1 + r2 + r3, avg);
```

The special way of aligning `{}` in if-else constructs is my favorite indentation style. In my opinion, but it is only an opinion, it also is defensive programming, because at least I do spot if-else-trees more easily like that and hence have a better chance of spotting mistakes. Using `{}` even for single-statement branches is also part of that, it defends against mistakes introduced by adding a statement to a single-statement `else` branch without `{}`.

Removing the logically unneeded `(temp[i] > 60) &&` defends against mistakes like

```
if (temp[i] < 60)
{
    r1++;
} else if ((temp[i] > 60) && (temp[i] < 84))
{
    r2++;
} else 
{
    r3++;
}
```

Because it avoids copying code (in this case the check against treshold 60) and the risk of inconsistencies between the two copies. In this case the mistake I introduces would result in a wrong classification of the edge case temperature 60.

Comment: Arguably, using `0.0f` which matches `float` but e.g. not precisely `double` , is against the defensive concept. That is an ingrained habit, it is not part of the intended introduction to defensive programming.